# How can I display a vimeo thumbnail background image in html using the vimeo ID?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

```
<div style="background: url('{{'https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/57666341.jpg'}}')">

</div>
```

I've tries examples using `https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/VIMEOID.jpg`

but the image showing at https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/57666341.jpg is a completely unrelated image to the video at https://vimeo.com/57666341 for example although they have the ID/

Answer (score 1):

A Vimeo video at https://vimeo.com/76979871 doesn't necessarily have a thumbnail URL located at https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/76979871.jpg.

To get a video's thumbnail links, try using [oEmbed](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos) with the video URL:

```
GET https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://vimeo.com/76979871
```

The `thumbnail_url` should be in the response, note that it does not share the "video_id":

```
https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/452001751_1280x720.png
```